# Yew callback for different Json structs

Tags: json, rust, json-rpc, serde, yew

I am using yew with the WebsocketService and sending jsonrpcs to a backend and receive the according answers. I have a problem to distinguish between valid and error jsonrpc answers.
Within the model implementation, I create the callback via:

```
let callback = self.link.callback(|Json(data)| {
    Msg::WsCallback(data)
});
```

WsCallback is a message with the actual response:

```
pub enum Msg {
    // ...
    WsCallback(Result<WsResponse, Error>),
}
```

and the response is the actual JsonRpc format:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct WsResponse {
    jsonrpc: String,
    result: String,
    id: i32,
}
```

Works fine for valid answers, but how do I handle the error-case of JsonRpc responses, which looks like this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct JsonRpcError{
    code: i32,
    message: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct WsResponseErr {
    jsonrpc: String,
    error: JsonRpcError,
    id: i32,
}
```

Is there some sort of match I can do on Json structs? As bonus-question: Is there a possibility to parse valid response with a result type different than String?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to parse a YAML containing a simple list together with a key-value list (associative array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793475/how-to-parse-a-yaml-containing-a-simple-list-together-with-a-key-value-list-ass)

Comment: use untaged + enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a wrapper with both types and add `untagged` attribute for `serde`:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum JsonRpcResult {
    Ok(WsResponse),
    Err(WsResponseErr),
}
```

> Is there a possibility to parse valid response with a result type different than String?

Yes, and I strongly recommend you to use your custom types there. You can use any type that implement `Deserialize` trait instead of `String`. You can read [here](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html) how to implement `Deserialize` or just use `derive` for your structs how you already did it above.